# How can I export a table in csv or txt format, with a concatenated name?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using a query to create a table, and then trying to export that table as a CSV file. Working in Access 2007.

I can get it to export as an XLS using the code below, but the named file has long spaces (not dots as shown) and is indented, when you look at it in the folder.

```
Example = [………….Factorysvc……….190601...………….]

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "CustItemExp", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)……
```

I've tried changing the XLS to CSV & TXT but get the following error:

> "The format in which you are attempting to output the current object is not available"

`dbo_setup` contains 2 fields:

- `droppath` = where to put the file
- `LocationName` = Factorysvc

Here is the complete code:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "CustItemExp", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", DLookup("droppath", "dbo_SetupExp") & DLookup("LocationName", "dbo_SetupExp") & Format(Date, "yymmdd") & ".xls", False, "", 0, acExportQualityPrint
```

Would like to get it to export a csv or text file with the `dbo_SetupExp.LocationName` and date created combined in the file name.

```
Example: FactorySvc190601.csv
```

Comment: When I posted the Example it got fixed. On my folder there are about 10 blank spaces before the F and another 10 between that and the date and the another 15 after the date

Comment: Have to mention, exporting to csv requires file's name to be not very long, with no dots in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without access to the data held in your `dbo_SetupExp` table, I can't explain the behaviour you are witnessing, however, in an attempt to workaround it I would suggest the following:

```vb
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "CustItemExp", acFormatXLS, _
    Trim(DFirst("droppath",     "dbo_SetupExp")) & _
    Trim(DFirst("LocationName", "dbo_SetupExp")) & _
    Format(Date, "yymmdd") & ".xls"
```

Aside, since you are not supplying the `DLookup` function with a `criteria` argument (and hence the function will return a random record from the table), `DFirst` seems like a more applicable function for this purpose.

To output the data to a `CSV` or `TXT` file instead of `XLS`, I would suggest using the [`TransferText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transfertext) method of the [`DoCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd) object, e.g.:

```vb
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "CustItemExp", _
    Trim(DFirst("droppath",     "dbo_SetupExp")) & _
    Trim(DFirst("LocationName", "dbo_SetupExp")) & _
    Format(Date, "yymmdd") & ".csv", True
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Any ideas on how to get it in csv or txt format?

Comment: But wait. Now when I change the CustItemExp table to include more then 100 days (increases the row count) and run; DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "CustItemExp", acFormatXLS, _
    Trim(DFirst("droppath",     "dbo_SetupExp")) & _
    Trim(DFirst("LocationName", "dbo_SetupExp")) & _
    Format(Date, "yymmdd") & ".xls" I get an error "There are two many rows to output, based on the limitations specified by the output format

Comment: Lee, that solution works GREAT - no error messages about output format. Curious though, what caused the two many rows error?

Comment: You're welcome. I think the `OutputTo` method has a limit of 65536 rows when exporting to an Excel spreadsheet. You can circumvent this by using the `TransferSpreadsheet` method instead, and reserve `OutputTo` for formats other than text or XLS.